# Where is equal to zero is so slow

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.6, mysql-8.0

I'm using Laravel 5.6 and MySQL for DB

```
public function getTopPaid(){
    $books = Book::with('users')->where('price', '>', 0 )->get()
        ->sortByDesc(function ($book){
            return $book->users->count();//sorting by purchased users count
        })->take(25);
    return new BooksWithAuthors($books);
}
```

I want to get the most purchased paid books with code above. And this is fine and response time from this is 1700 milliseconds. And about 400 records.

However the below code is almost the same:

```
public function getTopFree(){
    $books = Book::with('users')->where('price', '=', 0 )->get()
        ->sortByDesc(function ($book){
            return $book->users->count();
        })->take(25);
    return new BooksWithAuthors($books);
}
```

only 34 records in result,but the RESPONSE is in 8000 milliseconds. And the only difference in the code is
"equal"

```
where('price', '>', 0 )
```

and

```
where('price', '=', 0 )
```

Why the second query is so slow? And how to fix this

Comment: Both are two different query with two different set of output.

Comment: You say the first one takes 1700 milliseconds, and the second one takes 8 milliseconds. Then ask why the second is so slow. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, Chris Lear

Comment: Not the answer you want but if you are really concern with the performance you should avoid getting ALL records (`->get()`) from the database and then doing the aggregation in PHP (`->sortByDesc()`). Instead, you should leverage the aggregation to the database using a proper `groupBy` query. Otherwise your solution won't scale well when you have thousands of records (because you will always fetch all records but then keep only 25)

Comment: @AkbarTukhtamurodov are you sure? You want to know why the _second_ one is so slow? 8 is a lot less than 1700. The second query is potentially faster because it works on less records (due to the more precise `=`), possibly there is indexing involved, possibly possibly possibly. We don't have enough info to be certain.

Comment: ADyson, I had a mistake in writing, not 8 milliseconds, but 8000 ms i.e. 8 seconds, sorry

Comment: Computation time will scale with the amout of data you have to look at. So unless you would have some index on "count", more purchases mean longer execution time (assuming a proper index for the relation books->users, otherwise this will take time too and additionally scale with the amount of books). I could imagine that free books got "purchased" more often than paid ones. If that relation is *far* away from 1700/8000 you should mention that in your question, otherwise your execution times are expected (which doesn't mean you are unable to improve your query though).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL stores it's indexes by default in a BTREE. No hashing in general.

The short answer for the performance difference is that the > form evaluates more nodes then the = form.

Comment: I had a mistake in writing, not 8 milliseconds, but 8000 ms i.e. 8 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you often use the price column for searches
you can consider adding an index to the that column to improve performance:

```
CREATE INDEX books_price_idx ON books (price)
```